# Configuring gradle jetty plugin to use ssl

Tags: ssl, jetty, gradle

I've been trying to set up ssl with the gradle jetty plugin with no success. Also I've been unsuccessful in finding documentation related to it. Is there someone out there who can point me in the right direction to it?

**EDIT**

As part of the search I found out the following sample

```
jettyRun {
    def httpConnector = new org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector();
    httpConnector.port = 8080
    def httpsConnector = new org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector();
    httpsConnector.port = 8443
    httpsConnector.keystore = "keystore.jks"
    httpsConnector.keyPassword = "keystorepwd"
    httpsConnector.truststore = "cacerts"
    httpsConnector.trustPassword = "cacertspwd"
    connectors [httpConnector, httpsConnector]
}
```

But following that sample, left me with the following problem...

```
unable to resolve class org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector 
unable to resolve class org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector
```

Does I have to add some dependency in the build process. I've looked at the jar files as part of my gradle distribution and all seems correct.

EDIT 2

I have fixed the issue with the classpath, by adding the following

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.25'
    }
}
```

But now gradle complaints with the following message:

```
Cannot cast object 'SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080' with class 'org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector' to class 'org.mortbay.jetty.Connector'
```

If anyone seems to have found an answer I would greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution instead of importing the jar as a dependency I just simply load the class on the class loader for the jettyRun task. Something like the following

```
 httpConnector = jettyRun.class.classLoader.loadClass(....).newInstance()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could greatly simplify SSL/HTTPS part of your gradle scripts by using [Gretty gradle plugin](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty) instead of Jetty plugin.

It supports HTTPS with a single-line instruction:

```
gretty.httpsEnabled = true
```

It also provides lot of other useful functions, all documented at [Gretty documentation site](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/).

Disclosure: I am author of Gretty plugin.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the Jetty plugin doesn't provide any SSL functionality. If you are not bound to Jetty, you could use the [Tomcat plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) instead which allows to configure SSL.

Comment: I've found the following link on a spring [forum](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security/blobs/bbcc611af5899f6898536fdd1e2267c14e07d589/samples/cas/cas.gradle). I've tried that approach but, the problem I'm facing right now is that gradle complains with the following message 'unable to resolve class org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector'

Comment: Yeah, I meant out-of-the-box SSL functionality. Check the bundled Jetty JAR files in the Gradle distribution to see if the class is actually there. Maybe the package for the Jetty class did change between versions.

Comment: I've checked that already, and I'm sure they are there. What I'm not sure is if I have to do something else, classpath or some related configuration

Comment: It also complaints about the default connection 'org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector'

Comment: You are the author of the Tomcat Plugin right? how do you specify the truststore file and the truststore password?

Comment: Yeah, at the moment I don't but there's a [pull request](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin/pull/61) which I still need to merge. So it will be available soon.

Comment: @Angel Villalain: The latest version of the plugin does have this feature.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look